# CAPL function to stop CANoe

Tags: capl, canoe

I need to stop CANoe simulation automatically when a condition is reached in my CAPL code.

Are there some built-in functions to achive that or other option?

I've tried `stop()` but it is not working.

If there is not an available method. Does anyone know how to make a runtime error to force CANoe to stop?

Edit: The problem was That I was calling stop() from a timer. That timer was beeing called again before the stop() function executes so the timer were being be reset before the stop() function was executed.
Fixing that "loop" timer calling fixed the issue.

Comment: The CAPL command to stop the measurement (in online mode) is `stop()`. Could you elaborate on "is not working"?

Comment: I was calling the stop() method and the simulation still running for ever. But now is working. I was calling a timer to execute stop() after x seconds. The problem was i keep calling the timer before the timer finished, so I was reseting the timer before the timer is called.
Now I call the timer once and stop() works as is intended.